# Can't access to NAS

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, nas

I am on windows 8.1 and can't access to my folders stored on a Seagate Business Storage.

I had network drive connected, they worked fine until today. And I can't access by typing

> \\ip_of_nas

in the execute tab. Nothing is displayed, no error message. It make me think that the access take too long time to respond.

I tried to disconnect all my network drive with

> net use /del x:\

But nothing changed. When I ping my nas, all is fine.

I pinged it with a respond time =1 ms, time to live =64. So nothing is wrong

Any idea ?

PS : I can access to the nas folder with another computers/devices.
I tried to disable the firewall too. And nothing changed since yesterday, no software added, no services, nothing.

Comment: Did you wait a sufficiently long time? Error messages can appear anywhere from instantly (indicates a configuration problem) to multiple minutes later (indicates a communication problem). Did you restart your PC and/or the NAS device?

Comment: I waited for 10 min. That's long enough I think. I restarted the computer but nothing changed. I can't restart the NAS right now because many users are using it. But it works fine for everyone except one user.

Comment: What is the message you get ?

Comment: I have no message. I wait 10 min and no message shown.